# How can we establish a connection string in sqlserver 2008 using windows authentication?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can we establish a connection string in sqlserver  2008 using windows authentication? I hav used this code:

```
<add name="EmployeeDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=TVPC0006\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDatabase;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 2):

for a trusted connection you need to have:

```
Data Source =myServerAddress; 
Initial Catalog =myDataBase; 
Integrated Security =SSPI;
```

Comment: I tried,this code:<add name="EmployeeDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=TVPC0006\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="EmployeeDatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=TVPC0006\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: I have Tried this code: <add name="EmployeeDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=TVPC0006\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />.Sry again displaying same error.The server is in windows authentication

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).

You need  `Integrated Security=SSPI` or `Trusted_Connection = True;`

Comment: Thankyou.I have tried it but shows an error while logon" Cannot open database "Time_Sheet" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'TECHVANTAGE\T100008'. "

Comment: That suggests the user doesn't have permissions on the database.